# Displaying data from a txt file in a html element using Flask

Tags: python, html, list, file, flask

I currently have a text file which records "{level number}, {name}, {answer}" after a form is submitted in the text file *"incorrect_answers.txt"* as follows:

```
1, bob, answerone
1, nicky, answertwo
1, laura, answerthree
```

Using Python and Flask, my aim is to display the data in a table on an HTML page like this:

```
| Level | Name  | Answer      |
|   1   | bob   | answerone   |
|   2   | nicky | answertwo   |
|   3   | laura | answerthree |
```

At the moment, I am calling the data in the text file in the following function:

```
def get_incorrect_answers():

    with open("data/incorrect_answers.txt", "r") as file:
        incorrect_answers = file.readlines()

    return incorrect_answers
```

The result of this function is of course:

```
['1, bob, answerone\n', '1, nicky, answertwo\n', '1, laura, answerthree\n']
```

**Please can someone explain the best way to manipulate this output, so that I get a table displaying in HTML similar to what's been shown above?**

I'm having trouble accessing the values within the strings in the list

Comment: Your response doesn't render any html template. What is your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

since the text file has comma separated value, try

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('path to textfile', sep=',', header=None)
data.to_html()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data to the template renderer, then render it within the template with a loop, say this is your template called mytable.html

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
      {% for subfield in column_names %}
        <th>{{ subfield }}</th>
      {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% for item in incorrect_answers %}
<tr>
    {% for subitem in item %}
     <td> {{ subitem }}</td>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Then you render it with something like

```
@app.route('/incorrect_answers')
def get_incorrect_answers():

    with open("data/incorrect_answers.txt", "r") as file:
        incorrect_answers = file.readlines()

    return render_template('mytable.html', column_names=['Level', 'Name', 'Answer'], 
                           incorrect_answers=incorrect_answers)
```

When you go to http://localhost:port/incorrect_answers you will see your template appear.

Comment: Thanks @E.Serra for your answer. However, when I implement your code, I get each letter of an answer in it's own separate column, as opposed to each answer in it's own separate column. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: I asume it is iterqting twice(remember strings are alzó iterable in python) so it is probably getting the first one and iterqting on all its letterd. I suggest playing with the input útil you manage to give it a list, or playing with the loops beca use either of those is causing the issue

Comment: Actually if you remove the second loop for sub_item in ítem that should do it